# Parsing Bash redirects in Python3

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm currently writing a command parser module for a library in Python which will take fairly complex bash pipes, split them down and parse the individual segments.

The regex used for the parser isn't complicated but uses named groups:

```
/(?P<command>.*?)( ((?P<redirect>[&\d-]?)>+ ?&?(?P<filename>\S+)))( ?< ?(?P<infile>.*))?/g
```

In this form, I have been testing with the following [contrived] strings:

```
sed 's/24/25/g'                            # Doesn't pass but not necessary
sed 's/24/25/g' &>/dev/null                # Works
sed 's/24/25/g' 1>&2                       # Works
sed 's/24/25/g' 2>&1 1>/dev/null           # Works
sed 's/24/25/g' &>/dev/null < infile.txt   # Works
grep -rin --col 'i < 24\|b>19' > /dev/null            # Works
grep -rin --col 'i < 24\|b > 19' > /dev/null          # Doesn't work
```

I don't care about matching `sed 's/24/25/g'` on it's own as if there are no matches I can just assign the entire string as `command`, however the final `grep` would be problematic as it is entirely feasible that commands provided would contain the `>` symbol in this manner.

Question: Can this regex be re-written to encompass the final example *without resorting to using the `pcre` library*.

**Example: (python3)**

```
import re
import shlex
from collections import namedtuple

redirect_regex = re.compile(r"(?P<command>.*?)( (?P<redirect>[&\d]?)>+ ?&?(?P<filename>\S+))( ?< ?(?P<infile>.*))?", re.DOTALL)
command_list = [
    "sed 's/24/25/g'",
    "sed 's/24/25/g' &>/dev/null",
    "sed 's/24/25/g' 1>&2",
    "sed 's/24/25/g' 2>&1 1>/dev/null",
    "sed 's/24/25/g' &>/dev/null < infile.txt",
    "grep -rin --col 'i < 24\|b>19' > /dev/null",
    "grep -rin --col 'i < 24\|b > 19' > /dev/null"
]

command_structure = namedtuple('CommandStructure', 'command arguments redirects')
redirect = namedtuple('Redirect', 'stdout stderr stdin')
commands = []

for command in command_list:
    for com in command.split(' | '):
        structure = None
        matches = [match.groupdict() for match in redirect_regex.finditer(com)]
        if len(matches) == 0:
            structure = shlex.split(com)
            commands.append(
                command_structure(
                    command=structure[:1],
                    arguments=structure[1:],
                    redirects=None
                )
            )
        else:
            try:
                structure = shlex.split(matches[0]['command'])
            except ValueError as exception:
                print('Failed to parse command "' + com + '"')
                print('    reason was: ' + str(exception))
                continue
            structure_redirects = []
            for match in matches:
                stdout = match['filename'] if match['redirect'] in ['1', '', '&'] else None
                stderr = match['filename'] if match['redirect'] in ['2', '&'] else None
                stdin = match['infile'] if hasattr(match, 'infile') else None
                structure_redirects.append(
                    redirect(stdout=stdout, stderr=stderr, stdin=stdin)
                )
            commands.append(
                command_structure(
                    command=structure[:1],
                    arguments=structure[1:],
                    redirects=structure_redirects
                )
            )

print('--------------------------------')
for command in commands:
    print(command)
```

**Output**

```
Failed to parse command "grep -rin --col 'i < 24\|b > 19' > /dev/null"
    reason was: No closing quotation
--------------------------------
CommandStructure(command=['sed'], arguments=['s/24/25/g'], redirects=None)
CommandStructure(command=['sed'], arguments=['s/24/25/g'], redirects=[Redirect(stdout='/dev/null', stderr='/dev/null', stdin=None)])
CommandStructure(command=['sed'], arguments=['s/24/25/g'], redirects=[Redirect(stdout='2', stderr=None, stdin=None)])
CommandStructure(command=['sed'], arguments=['s/24/25/g'], redirects=[Redirect(stdout=None, stderr='1', stdin=None), Redirect(stdout='/dev/null', stderr=None, stdin=None)])
CommandStructure(command=['sed'], arguments=['s/24/25/g'], redirects=[Redirect(stdout='/dev/null', stderr='/dev/null', stdin=None)])
CommandStructure(command=['grep'], arguments=['-rin', '--col', 'i < 24\\|b>19'], redirects=[Redirect(stdout='/dev/null', stderr=None, stdin=None)])
```

Comment: I'd avoid quoting issues (always difficult with regex) by looking at [`shlex.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) or [`shlex.shlex()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html#shlex.shlex) and parse the string like a shell would.

Comment: Thank you but the issue doesn't actually come from quoting but the lazy quantifier breaking on the first ` > ` meaning shelx.split() gets an incomplete string. I'm trying to avoid `shelx.split()` for the parsing and am instead looking primarily for a regex solution.